# How to custom search bars in Ant Design ProTable

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Currently, I am using table of antd ProTable. I want to divide a column into two smaller ones, and each should has its equivalent search bar. However, it only shows the search bar for the parent column title (the one for Video as in picture).

I use ProTable because it has available search bar for every column in the table.

Thank you in advance!

[the demo table which a column has two smaller children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVyz2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-filter-panel-antd-4-20-2-forked-otcsho . This code is based on the customized filter panel of ant design: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel .
The main idea is to specify the two smaller columns as children of the bigger one, and then give them the property of search bar.

Comment: Thank @Clem. So, what I am trying to build is as the example in the Form action customization part in this docs https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/table?current=1&pageSize=5. It should have separated search bars instead of small modal trigger from inline search icon like in your example. Regardless the above requirement, your suggestion works nice!